# How to receive HTML response from WEB API in C#

Tags: c#, webapi

How to receive and print below error in C#.(See below screeshot)

[image]

This error is coming while posting the data to customer WEB API.

Code block used for Posting data to customer API.

```
var response = client.PostAsync(URL, content).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Status Code:" + (int)response.StatusCode); //output = 404
Console.WriteLine("Reason:" + response.ReasonPhrase); //output = Not Found
```

Please suggest?

Comment: Generally , u don't show the error message coming form the server as HTML. when u get and error for example 404- same as your case- you need to do your own handling. 
like when a 404 returned from the server you just return 404 by your own.

Comment: You've been here 13yrs you should have seen a few posts with screenshot error messages that people cant search?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this
var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();